# Is the viewport meta tag supported by the Amazon Silk browser on Kindle Fire?

Tags: cross-browser, viewport, meta-tags, kindle-fire, amazon-silk

I'm trying to use the viewport meta tag to scale HTML content when viewed on the Kindle Fire.

I have set up the following test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=2.5, maximum-scale=2.5, minimum-scale=2.5, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change the number from 2.5 to say 1.0 for example, this causes the content to be scaled down on the iPhone 4S. However, it appears to have no effect on the size of the content when viewed in the Amazon Silk browser on Kindle Fire.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a problem in my markup that could cause this?

Note:  I have tried changing the 'Desktop or mobile view' browser setting to Automatic, Mobile and Desktop - none of these settings changed anything about the appearance of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported:

> Keep in mind the following when developing web content for Silk and Fire devices:
>
> • The viewport is the portion of the browser dedicated to displaying the webpage. Viewport size and
> screen size for mobile devices are not necessarily identical. They differ because the browser uses up
> some screen real estate to show its chrome. You can use the viewport meta element (p. 36) to
> specify attributes of the viewport, including width and height.

Test each property by itself to determine specific support for each option:

- width
- height
- initial-scale
- minimum-scale
- maximum-scale
- user-scalable

**References**

- [Amazon Silk Developer Guide: CSS3 Support - viewport meta element (pdf)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/silk-dg.pdf)
- [Screen Resolution - Amazon Silk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/screen-size.html)
- [Dev.Opera — An Introduction to Meta Viewport and @viewport](https://dev.opera.com/articles/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/)
- [CSS Device Adaptation Module Level 1: Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#meta-properties)
- [Evidence Versus Proof](http://wiki.c2.com/?EvidenceVersusProof)
- [The 4 Types of Evidence ~ Writing Simplified](http://www.writingsimplified.com/2009/10/4-types-of-evidence.html)